# How can I store a URL into a session variable in MVC and later read it in an action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following on a razor page:

```
@{ Session["CurrentUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString(); }
```

I then call another page and in the POST action method of that second page I try to check the value of

```
var aaaa = Session["CurrentUrl"];
```

Can someone give me some advice as to why the value of variable aaaa is null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to store your data in TempData variable. TempData internally stores in session object.

```
in C# Code:

TempData["CurrentUrl"] = Request.Url.ToString();

in Razor View:

@{ string url = TempData["CurrentUrl"].ToString(); }
```

Hope this helps!